# Add attachment to email asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have feedback form on my site and I have `<input type="file">` in my form, so sometimes it will be need to add attachment to email.
I created `<input type="file">` in my form

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProjectInformation, null, new { type = "file", @class = "input-file" })
```

then in my controller I create email and try to add attachment

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        msg.From = new MailAddress("test@mail.ru", @Resources.Global.Feedback_Email_Title);
        msg.To.Add("tayna-anita@mail.ru");

        string message = @Resources.Global.Feedback_Name + ": " + Model.Name + "\n"
                        + @Resources.Global.Feedback_Email + ": " + Model.Email + "\n"
                        + @Resources.Global.Feedback_Phone + ": " + Model.Phone + "\n"
                        + @Resources.Global.Feedback_Company + ": " + Model.Company + "\n\n"
                        + Model.AdditionalInformation;
        msg.Body = message;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

        //Attachment
        if (Model.ProjectInformation != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase attFile = Model.ProjectInformation;
            int attachFileLength = attFile.ContentLength;
            if (attachFileLength > 0)
            {
                string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(Model.ProjectInformation.FileName);
                Model.ProjectInformation.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
                Attachment attach = new Attachment(Server.MapPath(strFileName));                   
                msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
                string attach1 = strFileName;
            }
        }

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = false;

        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        FeedbackForm tempForm = new FeedbackForm();
        return View(tempForm);
    }
```

but I think I need to delete attachment after sending and I try to add code here

```
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
            if (attach1 != null)
            File.Delete(Server.MapPath(attach1));
        }
```

but I get some mistakes

[image]

and

[image]

What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a variable before `if (Model.ProjectInformation != null)`

Something like this:

```
    string attach1;
    if (Model.ProjectInformation != null)
    {
        . . .
        if (attachFileLength > 0)
        {
            . . .
            attach1 = strFileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped, but the second mistake http://i.stack.imgur.com/aDFxO.png is not fixed.

Comment: @Heidel Invalid namespace, you should use `System.IO.File`

Comment: I use `using System.IO;` but it doesnt help, the same mistake.

Comment: @Heidel You still have namespace conflict. Replace `File.Delete()` with `System.IO.File.Delete()`, compiler can't understand which `File` you would like to use.

Comment: I tried to do that and this error disappeared, but I get other error http://i.imgur.com/rmjdVUf.png   but I dont understand why attach1 is unassigned if I declare it `string attach1;
    if (Model.ProjectInformation != null)
    {...}`

Comment: @Heidel It's possible, that your `if` check won't set value for `attach1` and compiler show error. Declare `attach1` with assignment: `string attach1 = null;`